# Is there a way to use a fake backend for ibm_brisbane?

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, ibm-quantum-devices

Is there a way to use a fake backend for ibm_brisbane?

I tried this but it is giving me the error that the backend is not present:

```
provider = FakeProvider()
backend = provider.get_backend('fake_brisbane')
```

Tried some of the suggestions from the below, but faced different issues with each:

---

**Solution 1:**

```
backend = provider.get_backend('ibm_brisbane')
backend_sim = qiskit_dynamics.DynamicsBackend.from_backend(backend, subsystem_list=[0,1,2,3])

from qiskit import transpile

circ = transpile(circuit, backend_sim)
job = backend_sim.run(circuit, shots=4096, seed_simulator=12345)
```

**Problem:**

```
TranspilerError: "Unable to translate the operations in the circuit: ['sx', 'measure', 'barrier', 'rz'] to the backend's (or manually specified) target basis: ['barrier', 'snapshot', 'measure']. This likely means the target basis is not universal or there are additional equivalence rules needed in the EquivalenceLibrary being used. For more details on this error see: https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.transpiler.passes.BasisTranslator.html#translation_errors"
```

---

**Solution 2:**

```
#Get the backend
backend = provider.get_backend('ibm_brisbane')

# transpile to backend
circ = transpile(circuit, backend=backend)

# create a simulator for backend
sim = AerSimulator().from_backend(backend)

# simulate and extract results
simulator_result = sim.run(circ).result()
simulator_counts = simulator_result.get_counts()
simulator_counts
```

**Problem:**

```
File c:\Users\Admin\.conda\envs\simuq\lib\site-packages\qiskit\transpiler\passmanager.py:553, in _replace_error.<locals>.wrapper(*meth_args, **meth_kwargs)
    551     return meth(*meth_args, **meth_kwargs)
    552 except PassManagerError as ex:
--> 553     raise TranspilerError(ex.message) from ex

TranspilerError: 'The input circuit None is not scheduled. Call one of scheduling passes before running the ConstrainedReschedule pass.'
```

**Note:** I verified that the circ object is not None and it has a valid list of 5 circuits

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of a bell state simulated experiment for an ibm_brisbane backend:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, transpile
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator
from qiskit_ibm_provider import IBMProvider

# get backend
provider = IBMProvider()
backend = provider.backends(name="ibm_brisbane")[0]

# create a bell circuit
circuit = QuantumCircuit(2, 2)
circuit.h(0)
circuit.cx(0, 1)
circuit.measure([0, 1], [0, 1])
circuit.draw()

# transpile to backend
circ = transpile(circuit, backend=backend)

# create a simulator for backend
sim = AerSimulator().from_backend(backend)

# simulate and extract results
simulator_result = sim.run(circ).result()
simulator_counts = simulator_result.get_counts()
simulator_counts
```

the results would look something like

```
{'01': 23, '10': 27, '11': 468, '00': 506}
```

Using

```
qiskit                   1.0.1
qiskit-aer               0.13.3
qiskit-ibm-provider      0.10.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried this, but I faced an error. I've added that error to the original question.

Comment: I noticed that I'm using qiskit 0.45 version. I'm trying to run the same after updaing qiskit. I'll let you know how it goes

Comment: Yup, the code is now working! After upgrading the packages the solution is working fine! Thanks @Roy for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
import qiskit_dynamics
import qiskit_ibm_provider
provider = qiskit_ibm_provider.IBMProvider()
print(provider.backends())
backend = provider.get_backend('ibm_brisbane')
backend_sim = qiskit_dynamics.DynamicsBackend.from_backend(backend, subsystem_list=[0, 1])
```

Here is a way to simulate circuits on 'fake_brisbane', while the subsystem_list is specified due to the qubits you want to use.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried this approach but faced an error. I've added that error to the original question for your reference.